# non-repeating column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.6

my query is like that:

```
SELECT o.id, o.title, oc.category_id,
(SELECT name from categories c where c.id = oc.category_id)
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN object_categories oc ON oc.object_id = o.id
WHERE type_id = 17
```

it returns me table like at the image

[image: my table]

I want to return non-repeating category name. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what is the result that you actually expect?

Comment: @GMB as you see in column `name` Bar repeating twice. I want that if any name more than 1, it returns only once

Comment: `(SELECT DISTINCT name from categories c where c.id = oc.category_id)` is probably something you are looking for.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can use the DISTINCT ON expression: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(c.id)
    o.id, 
    o.title, 
    oc.category_id,
    c.name,
    count(*) over(partition by o.id) cnt
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN object_categories oc ON oc.object_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.c.id = oc.category_id
WHERE type_id = 17 
ORDER BY c.id, o.id
```

When a category appears in than one record, this selects only the one that has the smallest object id.

I used the category id rather than the name to identify duplicates - you can use the category name instead, if that matters to you.

Note that I converted the inline subquery on `categories` to a regular `join`, since I find it more readable.